# Information not being submitted into the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I'm not quite sure what's going on, I've done almost everything I can think of to try and resolve this issue but I'm still stuck where I left off.

So the recovery questions are being submitted into the DB but when you are set to cancel them the cancel value doesn't change whatsoever.. I'm absolutely confused.

```
    <?php
/*
 * @CANCEL
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~
 * @FILE DESCRIPTION: Cancels set recovery questions
 * @LAST MODIFIED: August 29, 2015
 */

require('../includes/config.php');
require('../structure/database.php');
require('../structure/base.php');
require('../structure/user.php');

$database = new database($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_password);
$base     = new base($database);
$user     = new user($database);

//get config settings from db
$config = $base->loadConfig();

//set some basic vars
$username = $user->getUsername($_COOKIE['user'], 2);
$rank     = $user->getRank($username);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:IE>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="TRUE">
<title><?php
echo $data['wb_title'];
?></title>
<link href="../css/basic-3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="../css/main/title-5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="../css/kbase-2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" />
<?php
include('../includes/google_analytics.html');
?>
<style>
fieldset {
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #625437;
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
        background-color:transparent;
}

legend {
    color: #625437;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack()
{
    window.history.back();
}    
</script>
</head>

        <div id="body">
               <?php
$base->getNavBar($username, $path, $rank);
?><br/><br/>
                <br/><br/>
        <div style="text-align: center; background: none;">
                <div class="titleframe e">
                    <b>Cancel recovery questions</b><br />
                    <a href="../index.php">Main Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <img class="widescroll-top" src="../img/scroll/backdrop_765_top.gif" alt="" width="765" height="50" />
            <div class="widescroll">
            <div class="widescroll-bgimg">
            <div class="widescroll-content">
            <?php
if (!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo 'You must be logged in to access this content.';
} else {
    $info = $database->processQuery("SELECT `cancel` FROM `recoveries` WHERE `userid` = ?", array($user->getUserId($_COOKIE['user'])), true);
    //if ($database->getRowCount() == 1) {
    //echo 'You need to have recovery questions in order to cancel them. You can <a href="set_recov.php">set them here</a> or <a href="../index.php">return to the homepage</a>.';
    if ($info[0]['cancel'] >= 1) {
        echo 'Your recovery questions have already been set to cancel.';
    } elseif (isset($_GET['confirm'])) {
        //cancel the recovery questions
        $database->processQuery("UPDATE `recoveries` SET `cancel` = ? WHERE `userid` = ?", array(
            time(),
            $user->getUserId($_COOKIE['user'])
        ), false);

        echo '<center>Your recovery questions have successfully been set to cancel.<br><center><a href="../index.php">Main page</a></center>';
    } else {
?> 


                                        <b>Are you sure you wish to cancel your recovery questions?</b> Once you confirm this action your recovery questions will be active 
                                        for another two weeks, after that they will be deleted.<br><br> This action can be reversed by clicking the "Set recovery questions" link on the website homepage.
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <center><a href="cancel.php?confirm=1">I wish to continue</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="../index.php">I wish to go back</a></center>

                                    <?php
    }
}

?>
                      <center><img src="../img/kbase/scroll_spacer.gif" ></center>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <img class="widescroll-bottom" src="../img/scroll/backdrop_765_bottom.gif" alt="" width="765" height="50" />
        <div class="tandc"><?php
echo $data['wb_foot'];
?></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As for this being commented out

```
 //if ($database->getRowCount() == 1) {
    //echo 'You need to have recovery questions in order to cancel them. You can <a href="set_recov.php">set them here</a> or <a href="../index.php">return to the homepage</a>.';
```

It's because if it is, when the page is loaded that's all that shows...nothing else, even if the recovery options are set in the database.

Any ideas? really stuck here.

Comment: Seems like you have something wrong with the number of curly brackets. What you've commented out has an opening bracket but doesn't have a closing one. Close the IF statement and you should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` Try placing this somewhere in the beginning of the script because it appears that there is an error somewhere

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home3/rsrebor2/public_html/recovery/cancel.php on line 94 which is         if ($info[0]['cancel'] >= 1) {

Comment: do a `echo "<pre>" . print_r($info, true) . "</pre>";` to see the structure of $info and make sure that it has index 0

Comment: Undefined variable: info in /home3/rsrebor2/public_html/recovery/cancel.php on line 89

Comment: Place it right before the piece that you commented out or right before the if statement:  `if ($info[0]['cancel'] >= 1) {`

Comment: It just says this                                                                                          Array
(
)

Comment: So it appears that your select query is not returning anything. To prevent that from happening change it to : `if (isset($info[0]['cancel']) && $info[0]['cancel'] >= 1) {`

Comment: I did that and the value in the database still hasn't changed.